# Where's the flaw in my algorithm to find the largest subset whose every pair's sum doesn't divide K?

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I've left comments about what my logic is. The way it's supposed to work is that, for example, if we have `K=3` and `S={1,7,2,4}`, the largest subset whose every pair's sum doesn't divide `K` is `{1,7,4}`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

class Solution
{
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        int k = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine().Split(' ')[1]);
        var S = Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(' '), Int32.Parse);

        // first get all pairs in S whose sum doesn't divide k, 
        // each pair in their own subset set of S
        var subsets = from i in S
                      from j in S
                      where i < j && ((i + j) % k != 0)
                      select new HashSet<int>() { i, j };

        // for each subset, for each number in the original set 
        // not already in the subset, if the number summed with
        // every numer in the subset doesn't divide k, add the
        // number to the subset
        foreach(var ss in subsets)
             foreach(int n in S.Where(q => !ss.Contains(q)))
                if(ss.All(m => (m + n) % k != 0))
                   ss.Add(n);

        // get the size of the largest subset, print to console
        int max = subsets.Select(ss => ss.Count).Max();
        Console.WriteLine(max);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you give a input that fails?

Comment: The one in my example fails. That example is from https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/non-divisible-subset?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen

Comment: I'm wondering how many questions you'll post until realizing that LINQ queries has to be materialized into some memory collection in case they are used more than once. `subsets.Select(..` just creates new `HastSet`s, thus throwing out everything you did in the previous loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm to the problem maybe wrong though, the unexpected behavior is due to a bug in your code. (But even if you fix it, I think it's too slow for the online judge, also you may miss some tricky cases, you can try to submit it).

`HashSet` object `subsets` is not updated as when you call `Add`, the integer is added to the copy of another `HashSet`.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;


public class Test
{
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        ...
       foreach(var ss in cnt){
             foreach(int n in S.Where(q => !ss.Contains(q)))
                if(ss.All(m => (m + n) % k != 0)){
                   ss.Add(n);
                }
          // Log here, you will see the size is updated to 3
            Console.WriteLine(ss.Count);
        }
        // Log here, it is still printing 2 !         
        foreach(var ss in cnt)
             Console.WriteLine(ss.Count);
        // get the size of the largest subset, print to console
        int max = ...
        Console.WriteLine(max);
    }
}
```

A simple fix is to new a global list of hashset first, and update that list

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;


public class Test
{
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        int k = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine().Split(' ')[1]);
        var S = Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(' '), Int32.Parse);
        List<HashSet<int>> cnt = new List<HashSet<int>>();
        // first get all pairs in S whose sum doesn't divide k, 
        // each pair in their own subset set of S
        cnt = (from i in S
                      from j in S
                      where i < j && ((i + j) % k != 0)
                      select new HashSet<int>() { i, j }).ToList();

        // for each subset, for each number in the original set 
        // not already in the subset, if the number summed with
        // every numer in the subset doesn't divide k, add the
        // number to the subset

        foreach(var ss in cnt){
             foreach(int n in S.Where(q => !ss.Contains(q)))
                if(ss.All(m => (m + n) % k != 0)){
                   ss.Add(n);
                }
        }

        // get the size of the largest subset, print to console
        int max = cnt.Max(ss => ss.Count);
        Console.WriteLine(max);
    }
}
```

---

However, this problem can be solved easily in `O(k)` (if not count I/O time which is `O(N)`)

Here is my accepted code in C++

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int n,k,a,c[105] = {0},ans=0;
int main() {
    cin >> n >> k;
    for(int i=0; i<n;i++) cin >> a, c[a%k]++;

    for(int i=1; i<=k/2; i++){
        if(k%2 == 0 && i==k/2 && c[i]) ans++;
        else ans += max(c[i], c[k-i]);
    }
    if(c[0] && ans) ans++;
    if(!ans) ans++;
    cout << ans << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The concept behind this is the modular arithmetic:

`(a+b)%k = 0  is equavalent to (a%k + b%k)%k = 0`

So actually, we just count how many elements that modular k is equal to 0,1,2...k-1, store them in `c[0], c[1]...c[k-1]`

Then logically, for those numbers in `c[1]` & `c[k-1]` cannot be choose together, so we choose the one with larger count. Similarly, `c[2] & c[k-2]` cannot be choose together, etc.

There is some special cases though, you may see my code and check it out.

One more tricky place to aware of this problem is (which I think it's bad written problem statement), if the result set size is one, then it's always a valid set even the only element is divisible by k. (i.e., ans will never be 0)

Answer (score 0):

In your second loop, when you write `ss.Add(n);`
you add 'n' to a COPY of the hashset ss.

so after the foreach section, `subsets` remains with the previous sets.

you can manually calculate the max inside the foreach as a quick solution

Answer (score -1):

With your approach you will figure out the subset with all the numbers meeting the condition, but you don´t add the subset of numbers to your overall `subsets`. So when you are looking for the largest subset you won´t find the correct one.

```
    foreach(var ss in subsets)
    {
         foreach(int n in S.Where(q => !ss.Contains(q)))
         {
            if(ss.All(m => (m + n) % k != 0))
               ss.Add(n);
         }
     //Add the subset ss to subsets or replace it
    }
```